# Writing data from a file to multidimensional array

Tags: c++, fstream

Cannot load array named 'numbers' with a data from a txt file.
I've tried number of combinations:

```
fin_fout.read((char*)(numbers[i]),number_length);
fin_fout.read((char*)(&numbers[i]),number_length);
fin_fout.read((char*)(numbers[i][0]),number_length);
fin_fout.read((char*)(&numbers[i][0]),number_length);
```

None of them will work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Reader
    {

public://change this to private
    static const unsigned numbers_in_file = 200;
    static const unsigned number_length = 100;
    static char numbers[numbers_in_file][number_length];
    static std::fstream fin_fout;
    static
        inline
        void read_unsafe_()
    {

        for (unsigned i = 0; !fin_fout.eof();++i)
        {
            fin_fout.read((char*)(numbers[i]),number_length);
        }
        fin_fout.close();
    }
}
/*this stream will be reading and writing to a file*/
std::fstream Reader::fin_fout("data.txt",
    std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
```

**Error 1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'char [100]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)**

Comment: Describe "Doesn't work", please

Comment: So, post the compiler error message!

Comment: @smallB:  I believe you are missing a `sizeof` in the length specifier.  Your `read` statements are reading 100 *characters*, not `int`s.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @Thomas, no I believe that number_length is suppose to say how "long" is the "line" (how many chars) I'm reading in, and that's why it is there

Comment: @downvoters anyone with guts to admit what for this downvote?

Comment: @smallB - don't know about the downvote, but the code compiles for me, so maybe you should check it again? I'm using gcc version 4.4.3

Comment: @littleadv I'm using VS2010 sp1 and it definitely doesn't compile. And I must use VS

Comment: @smallB - every nanosecond counts but you're running on Windows? you're strange.

Comment: @littleadv and what's so strange? if I have this program running over bilion times, what's so strange, do you mind answering?

Comment: @smallB - windows is not a real-time OS, and there's no time constraint on file reads. Disk I/O usually is the bottleneck, so if you're reading over billion times a 100-chars string from a file, the nano-second difference between the built-in array and an STL container is just meaningless compared to the IO delays and OS scheduling impact that you will have.

Comment: @little and I'll repeat again that it is not read from file but creation of containers what counts.

Comment: @smallB - This sounds like an odd homework exercise. Can you supply the original problem? There are appear to be some strange and mysterious constraints that limit what you code can and can't do. We could help a lot more if we knew what they were and the reasons why they are there or why you have to even use C++.

Comment: @smallB - static class members are created when you start your program. Really, that's what matters? Have you actually measured your performance and identified an issue, or you're just optimizing because someone told you that you should?

Answer (score 1):

Since your numbers are in a text file, I'm stipulating they are represented as text, such as "124", which would be the characters '1', '2', '4'.

My recommendation is that you translate these textual representations into internal representations before storing them into an array:

```
  int number;
  fin_fout >> number;
  array[i] = number;
```

One of the problems with storing the numbers as text, is that they are a variable field.  The textual representation "5" contains less characters than "31415264".  When you allocate a 2D array, you will have to allocate enough space for the longest possible textual representation.

The better method is to read the data from the file, convert to a number, store into a vector, then repeat until EOF.  The `std::vector` is a great container for this purpose because it expands as necessary, which is required when handling data files (especially when there is no guarantee about the quantity of data in the file).

Try something like this:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int number_from_file;
while (fin_fout >> number_from_file)
{
    numbers.push_back(number_from_file);
}
const unsigned int NUMBERS_IN_FILE = numbers.size();

//...
std::cout << "First number from file: " << numbers[0] << "\n";
std::cout.flush();
```

Also, about performance:  "every nanosecond counts" cannot apply when reading from a file.  *File reading performance is out of the program's control and dependent on the OS.*  If file I/O performance is an issue, read the entire file into memory, then parse the numbers from memory.  This technique is only recommended to advanced programmers and only when performance is critical.  You'll spend more development time getting a complex process to work correctly than implementing a slower, simpler process.

### Edit 1:

**Advanced Technique 1:**

1. Read entire file into a string.
2. Use `std::stringstream` to parse the
   numbers from the string.

**Advanced Technique 2:**

1. Open the text file as "memory
   mapped". *You'll need platform
   specific functionality for this.*
2. Parse the memory for numbers.

**Advanced Technique 3:**
Design your program for multiple threads.  One thread reads a number, using the simple technique, and places it into a circular queue.  This thread sets a signal indicating a number is ready.  Another "processing" thread sleeps on the signal.  When the signal is activated, the processing thread fetches the number from the queue and processes it.  Search the web for "double buffering".

**Advanced Technique 4:**

1. Read file into a buffer.
2. Use custom function to transform
   textual representation into internal
   numeric representation.
   You may gain some performance here over Techniques 1 & 2 above because you can tailor the custom function for only numbers.

Comment: @Thomas cannot use neither vector nor any other container. Must be built-in array. Every nanoseconds counts refers to creation of object not reading a file. number_length is the max length of a number in this file.

Comment: @smallB:  The `std::vector` has a constructor that allows you to specify the maximum size (or at least the size to start with).  The time creating a vector of fixed size is not much more than allocating an array.  The time being much smaller than the I/O time.

Comment: @Thomas I've compared many container creation times to built-in arrays and specifiyng designed vector size is of little importance. The pure "object creation" built-in versus container, that's what counts.

Comment: @Thomas and correct me if I'm wrong but vector would keep data on heap not on the stack isn't that so? As you see from my code array is on the stack.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your advanced techniques, but would you mind answering to a question I've asked originally?

Comment: @smallB - Your speed bottleneck here is your disk access not your vector implementation. Your code will be idle waiting for the disk. More detail on the problem would help since it seems very odd. We may need specific os and hardware details to consider stuff like disk caching and the specific version of the compiler and OS you are using.